# galvanic corrosion with anchor point on galvalume roofing

Tags: roof, metal-roof, galvanic-corrosion

I'm going to add some sort of anchor point, for attaching a safety rope, to my galvalume roof (some sort of shoulder eye bolt, but that is a different discussion).   My question, what metal is best for this bolt ?   Stainless is the obvious choice, but I gather it would have substantial galvanic corrosion.   Should I just use zinc-coated or galvanized ?  Or would it be better to use stainless, for best corrosion resistance of the eye bolt itself, and attempt to electrically isolate it from the galvalume panel that it penetrates, probably using the same silicon caulk I'd use to seal against water leaks ?

Comment: So you want to attach a _shackle_ to the roof, and avoid it getting _Rusty_, is that right?

Comment: Hardy har har !

Comment: Couldn't resist...  So . is the plan to drill a hole in the galvalume big enough for the shaft of the bolt and have that screw into some wood?  Or will this be like a plate mount that screws through the roof material?

Comment: Use stainless, for eye bolt longevity (since you're using it as a fall protection anchor) and isolate it from dissimilar material with nylon washers top and bottom. If you're worried about contact at the through-hole, use a short sleeve of plastic tubing or pvc, or just center it through a slightly oversize hole.

Comment: Yes, @Jphi1618, a hole through the galvalume, for the shaft of either a regular eyebolt, as discussed in OP of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/134478/attaching-eye-bolt-to-roof-ridgeline or a lag eye, as in one of the comments on that question.   Probably the latter.

Comment: Thanks, Jimmy, that's kinda what I was thinking too.   This one looks like the ticket (probably the largest, with 1/2" x 4-3/4" shank:  http://www.safelandindustrial.com/app/stx.productdetail.asp?did=95#.WrPr-ZPwbOR

Comment: Yea, in that case i was thinking along the lines of what Jimmy says.  @JimmyFix-it, make that an answer.

Comment: I can find what I need here, stainless shoulder eye lag, at only one place (link is 2 comments back), that has $50 order.   Bummer.   I've checked all the likely suspects, even MacMaster-Carr.